# Object count program in java

Tags: object, count

I am a java beginner. I am not able to understand this below piece of code.

I am trying to count the number of objects for A and B class. Number of A objects in A is 4 and so it is for B. However if I try to access AA.print for the second time it is outputs 8.

Please help.

```
package scripts;

 class AA {
    static  int cntr = 0;
    AA(){
        cntr++;
    }
}

 class BB extends AA{
     static  int cntr = 0;  
        BB(){
            cntr++;
        }
 }

public class objCount{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AA a1 = new AA();
        new AA();
        new AA();
        new AA();
        System.out.println("A class objects"+" "+AA.cntr);     //A

        BB b1 = new BB();
        new BB();
        new BB();
        new BB();
        System.out.println("B class objects"+" "+BB.cntr);      //4
        System.out.println("A class objects"+" "+AA.cntr);      //8
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BB` inherits from `AA`:

```
class BB extends AA
```

Which means every time you do this:

```
new BB()
```

The constructor for `BB` ***and*** the constructor for `AA` execute.  So your code is incrementing the counter in `AA` 8 times:

```
AA a1 = new AA(); // AA - 1
new AA();         // AA - 2
new AA();         // AA - 3
new AA();         // AA - 4
BB b1 = new BB(); // AA - 5, BB - 1
new BB();         // AA - 6, BB - 2
new BB();         // AA - 7, BB - 3
new BB();         // AA - 8, BB - 4
```